# What is the memory footprint of a session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

Would it be more efficient to store a single session variable with a serialized json object, a c# object, or a comma seperated string vs 3 different session variables? I don't know what the overall footprint of each session variable is, but I'm worried about session cache bloat on the server side.

ex.

```
Session["some id"] = "{ name: "name", "id": "some id", "image": "image url" }"
```

or

```
Session["name"] = "some name"
Session["id"] = "user id"
Session["image"] = "some image url"
```

I'm just looking to use whatever has the smallest footprint

Comment: The above methods make very little difference, I suggest concentrating on what goes in the cache at the first place... if your cache is bloated, it is because you are storing too many things... not because you are storing them inefficiently... having said that, your second method take less space. because you are not storing json variable name ("name", "id", "image") in the cache, you are just storing their values.

Comment: bloating the cache is concerning for me because I might end up having a great number of users and each user gets this session data stored. What if I have > 1 mimllion users logged in at once?

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't store 1 million user's data in memory... you could put the data in a cookie and this way each request would contain that specific user's data, see [Brock Allen's Cookie based TempData provider](https://brockallen.com/2012/06/11/cookie-based-tempdata-provider/)... again I don't know your design, but you can always store the data in the DB... Session variable is meant to be small.

Comment: Here's my problem. I load a partial page in my layout if the user is logged in. This is a instant chat box. I want to load a couple pieces into that chat box from those session variables. So I didn't want to do a db fetch each time I load a view, especially since I have a shit ton of views

Comment: Why don't you put that in a cookie? if it is small amount of data, it can go back and forth with the request.

Comment: I've never used cookies, would I have to fetch the data and put it in a cookie with each page load?

Comment: I have provided a link above... you just need to configure your TempData to be stored in a Cookie... there are quite a few SO posts on the topic as well.